# How can I round manually?

Tags: java, math, rounding

I'd like to round manually without the round()-Method.
So I can tell my program that's my number, on this point i want you to round. 
Let me give you some examples:
Input number: 144
Input rounding: 2
Output rounded number: 140

Input number: 123456
Input rounding: 3
Output rounded number: 123500

And as a litte addon maybe to round behind the comma:
Input number: 123.456
Input rounding: -1
Output rounded number: 123.460

I don't know how to start programming that...
Has anyone a clue how I can get started with that problem?

Thanks for helping me :)

I'd like to learn better programming, so i don't want to use the round and make my own one, so i can understand it a better way :)

Comment: What type of numbers are you trying to round?  (If you're trying to round floating-point numbers without any built-in tools...don't.  Just don't.)

Comment: Is this for homework?

Comment: He said in his post that he wants to do it so that he understand how rounding works. Understanding the underlying features of a program is something nice to do.

Comment: What are these "input rounding" values?  They seem to be 1 off from what I would expect.  0 should round to the nearest integer, 2 should round to the nearest 100 and -2 should round to the nearest hundredth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do it is:

1. Divide the number by a power of ten
2. Round it by any desired method
3. Multiply the result by the same power of ten in step 1

Let me show you an example:

You want to round the number `1234.567` to two decimal positions (the desired result is `1234.57`).

```
x = 1234.567;
p = 2;
x = x * pow(10, p);  // x = 123456.7
x = floor(x + 0.5);  // x = floor(123456.7 + 0.5) = floor(123457.2) = 123457
x = x / pow(10,p);   // x = 1234.57
return x;
```

Of course you can compact all these steps in one. I made it step-by-step to show you how it works. In a compact java form it would be something like:

```
public double roundItTheHardWay(double x, int p) {
    return ((double) Math.floor(x * pow(10,p) + 0.5)) / pow(10,p);
}
```

As for the integer positions, you can easily check that this also works (with `p < 0`).

Hope this helps

Comment: What's the purpose of the `int p` argument in your `roundItTheHardWay` method? It looks like you never use it. Did you intend to replace `pow(10,2)` with `pow(10,p)` or perhaps `pow(10,-p)`?

Comment: what exactly does floor? I found something at Google that floor returns a integer? Is that correct? Or is that... OH! I see it... okay :D get it! Thanks

Comment: @MikroByte `floor(x) = n` where `n` is the greatest integer that is less or equal to `x`. check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)

Comment: @Barranka You might still have a sign problem with p, based upon the intent in the OP since you are initially multiplying `pow(10,p)` by x and then dividing the result back out to get the decimal in the correct position.

Comment: @andand that's exactly what I intend to do... The process I ilustrated is: 1. Put all the relevant positions in the integer part of the number. 2. Add `0.5`. 3. Truncate the decimal portion of the number. 4. Divide again to get the decimal in the right place. (That's why I named the method `roundItTheHardWay` ;-) It's a way to do it (not the most efficient, but it works)

Comment: Right, but given the intent of the OP, p=2 should (probably) round to the nearest hundred, not the nearest hundredth.  I think there's a slight error in the question; his notion of what results should be returned for a given value of p are off by 1, but his intent seems clear enough.

Comment: Well, it can be done by simply interchanging `x * pow(10,p)` and `x / pow(10,p)` and using negative values of `p` for "rounding after the point" and positive values of `p` for "rounding before the point".

Answer (score 1):

if you need some advice how to start,

- step by step write down calculations what you need to do to get from 144,2 --> 140
- replace your math with java commands, that should be easy, but if you have problem, just look  [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int round (int input, int places) {
  int factor = (int)java.lang.Math.pow(10, places);
  return (input / factor) * factor;
}
```

Basically, what this does is dividing the input by your factor, then multiplying again. When dividing integers in languages like Java, the remainder of the division is dropped from the results.

**edit:** the code was faulty, fixed it. Also, the java.lang.Math.pow is so that you get 10 to the n-th power, where n is the value of `places`. In the OP's example, the number of places to consider is upped by one.

**Re-edit:** as pointed out in the comments, the above will give you the *floor*, that is, the result of rounding  **down**. If you don't want to always round down, you must also keep the *modulus* in another variable. Like this:

```
int mod = input % factor;
```

If you want to always get the *ceiling*, that is, rounding **up**, check whether `mod` is zero. If it is, leave it at that. Otherwise, add `factor` to the result.

```
int ceil = input + (mod == 0 ? 0 : factor);
```

If you want to round to nearest, then get the floor if `mod` is smaller than `factor` / 2, or the ceiling otherwise.

Comment: works great, but i have a litte adjustment to do because it doesn't look at the following: 1234567 is roundet to 1234500 but it has to be 1234600. ;) thanks for that code-snippet

Comment: Won't this give you the "floor" rather than the "round" of the input?

Comment: @jfrank is right. This is giving the *floor*. If you want the *ceiling*, that is, rounding **up** instead of rounding **down**, then also check whether (input % factor) == 0. If it does, leave it at that, otherwise, add factor to the result.

Comment: The OP wanted something that worked with `float` or `double`, but this only works with `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Divide (positive)/Multiply (negative) by the "input rounding" times 10 - 1 (144 / (10 * (2 - 1)). This will give you the same in this instance. Get the remainder of the last digit (4). Determine if it is greater than or equal to 5 (less than). Make it equal to 0 or add 10, depending on the previous answer. Multiply/Divide it back by the "input rounding" times 10 - 1. This should give you your value.

If this is for homework. The purpose is to teach you to think for yourself. I may have given you the answer, but you still need to write the code by yourself.

Next time, you should write your own code and ask what is wrong

Comment: thank you, it's not for homework ;) like i write, i want to know how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

For integers, one way would be to use a combination of the mod operator, which is the percent symbol %, and the divide operator.  In your first example, you would compute 144 % 10, resulting in 4.  And compute 144 / 10, which gives 14 (as an integer).  You can compare the result of the mod operation to half of the denominator, to find out if you should round the 14 up to 15 or not (in this case not), and then multiply back by the denominator to get your answer.

In psuedo code, assuming n is the number to round, p is the power of 10 representing the position of the significant digits:

```
denom = power(10, p)
remainder = n % denom
dividend = n / denom
if (remainder < denom/2)
  return dividend * denom
else
  return (dividend + 1) * denom
```